# Fail2Ban - How to block BruteForce on install.php files?

Tags: wordpress, security, plesk, fail2ban, jail

an IP address attack my server with **BruteForce** scanning of **install.php** Wordpress files:

```
/var/www/vhosts/website1.tld/logs/access_ssl_log:104.248.227.52 - - [28/Jul/2021:08:27:33 +0200] "GET /wp-admin/install.php HTTP/1.1" 200 5503 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36"

/var/www/vhosts/website2.tld/logs/access_ssl_log:104.248.227.52 - - [28/Jul/2021:08:27:43 +0200] "GET /wp-admin/install.php HTTP/1.1" 403 5686 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36"

/var/www/vhosts/website3.tld/logs/access_ssl_log:104.248.227.52 - - [28/Jul/2021:08:27:35 +0200] "GET /wp-admin/install.php HTTP/1.1" 200 6290 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36"

/var/www/vhosts/website4.tld/logs/access_log:104.248.227.52 - - [28/Jul/2021:08:27:44 +0200] "GET /wp/wp-admin/install.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1296 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36"

/var/www/vhosts/website5.tòd/logs/access_ssl_log:104.248.227.52 - - [28/Jul/2021:08:27:41 +0200] "GET /wordpress/wp-admin/install.php HTTP/1.1" 404 6219 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36"

etc...
```

How can I **block this actions**?

Please note that **install.php** is also **used for installations** and therefore I **cannot block any requests**!

Thanks for support,
Regards,
Gian Marco.

Comment: Can you check the syslog and use the default php sysadmin jail [https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/master/config/filter.d/phpmyadmin-syslog.conf] in fail2ban 1.01? It seems that you should be looking for the error message of the failed attempt and not then attempt itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a filter using using a regex to spot hits on the install.php
Then a create jail for a lot of hits within a short window.
Slightly dirty but this regex might work:

```
 _log:(<ADDR>).*GET.*install.php
```